# rake doc:app is not working in Rails 5 API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Here is the Gemfile after creating standalone rails5 api application:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.0'
# Use mysql as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2', '>= 0.3.18', '< 0.5'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
# gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use Rack CORS for handling Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS), making cross-origin AJAX possible
# gem 'rack-cors'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

The command used:

```
rake doc:app
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for `rake doc:app` and `rails doc:app` has been completely removed in Rails 5.

Please see section 3.1 Removals in the [Rails 5 release notes](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/5_0_release_notes.html#railties-removals).

You can also the rationale for this removal [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/cd7cc5254b090ccbb84dcee4408a5acede25ef2a).

Comment: That's right. Rails recommends that users now write their own scripts to replace `doc:app`.